# Ruby method visibility: undefined method?

Tags: ruby, methods, visibility, nomethoderror

i'm still new to ruby. i dont understand the methods visibility. the documentation says, all methods are public by default (unless defined otherwise). so this should work (but it doesn't, MWE):

`modules/example.rb`:

```
class Example

  def do_stuff
    puts 'hello world'
  end

end
```

and `testing.rb`:

```
load 'modules/example.rb'

Example.new
Example.do_stuff
```

calling `$ ruby testing.rb`
results in

```
testing.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `do_stuff' for Example:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Can someone explain why? And how to fix it that I can call `do_stuff` directly?

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted? Voted up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining an instance method and need to call it on an instance of Example class:

```
ex_instance = Example.new
ex_instance.do_stuff
```

If you want to call it directly you need to define it as a class method:

```
class Example

  def self.do_stuff
    puts 'hello world'
  end

end
```

then you can call it like this without the need of calling `Example.new`

```
Example.do_stuff
```

Comment: thanks. i was blind - that was really stupid. :)